# Ambiguous field mapping detected Issue

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, redis

Getting the following Exception in my spring boot mongo application

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException:
>   Ambiguous field mapping detected! Both private final
>   java.lang.reflect.Type
>   org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.type and private final
>   java.lang.Class
>   org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.type map to the
>   same field name type! Disambiguate using @Field annotation!   at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity$AssertFieldNameUniquenessHandler.assertUniqueness(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:296)
>   ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity$AssertFieldNameUniquenessHandler.doWithPersistentProperty(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:283)
>   ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity$AssertFieldNameUniquenessHandler.doWithPersistentProperty(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:277)
>   ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:330)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.verifyFieldUniqueness(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:157)
>   ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.verify(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:149)
>   ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:332)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]

The thing is none of those fields("type") are under my control. Need help in this.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import com.xyz.abc.core.model.ConfigEntity;

/**
 * 
 * @author asdasd.asdafsfg
 *
 */
public interface ConfigRepository extends MongoRepository<ConfigEntity, String> {

    public ConfigEntity findById(String id);

}
```

My ConfigEntity.java looks like this

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mapping.Association;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

/**
 * 
 * @author vinay.shivanna
 *
 */
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection="configstore")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ConfigEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5484736588242242417L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("defaultAssociations")
    private List<Association> defaultAssociations;

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("profileAssociations")
    private List<Association> profileAssociations;

}
```

I am using spring mongo starter dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Spring boot version is 1.5.7.RELEASE

I se that Association class which is coming from `spring-data-commons-1.13.7-RELEASE` jar is extending a class PersistentProperty which internally extends itself.. like this `PersistentProperty<P extends PersistentProperty<P>>`  This class has type Property.Thats the one which is given in the stacktrace.. But i really don't have the solution. Need help

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the full tack trace. Do you have any inheritance between your entities. Did you check these 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120786/mappingexception-ambiguous-field-mapping-detected  and https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-694

Comment: added full stack trace.. i dont have any inheritance.. i have put the complete referenced java content of all the related classes

Comment: @pvpkiran added some more details upon debugging.. You were right of the inheritance part of it..

Comment: how was this fixed?

Comment: Having a similar problem with DB2 classes.